# IP table rule to block telnet packet for particular active port but not other type of packets

Tags: linux, iptables

In my Linux device port 5080 is open which accepts all packets. I want to block only telnet packets.

I tried to add iptable rule but i am not sure how to specifically mention telnet packets only because adding iptable rule with protocol tcp blocks all the tcp packets and telnet but I want to block only telnet packets.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1  -p tcp --dport 5080 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with iptables.
You'll need some application layer aware IPS (maybe **[suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/)**?)